# How to start a play2 application on a remote machine using capistrano

Tags: scala, capistrano, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to deploy a play2 application with capistrano, but I can't figure out how to (re)start the play2 application after a successful deployment. Just triggering 'play start' will cause the process to be hanging waiting for me to press ctrl+D

I've created a start script in the play app root folder

```
#!/bin/bash

nohup bash -c "/var/lib/play2/play start &>> /tmp/myapp.log 2>&1" &> /dev/null &
```

It works great when I run this on the server. When I try to call this from my local machine over ssh it also works. But when I am using capistrano, it doesn't seem to do anything. My capistrano config looks like this:

```
namespace :deploy do

  task :restart do
    stop
    sleep 1
    start
  end

  task :start do
    run "cd #{current_release}/trip-api && ./start.sh"
  end

  task :stop do
    run "cd #{current_release}/trip-api && ./stop.sh"
  end
end
```

What's the best way to start a play2 application on a remote machine? How to get it working with capistrano?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at play documentation on [deploying your application on production](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.1/Production)

The recommended way is to package your app with

```
play clean compile stage
```

And then run it with

$ target/start

To stop it, have a look at the docs:

> The server’s process id is displayed at bootstrap and written to the
>   RUNNING_PID file. To kill a running Play server, it is enough to send
>   a SIGTERM to the process to properly shutdown the application.

In this [quickstart for Openshift](https://github.com/opensas/play2-openshift-quickstart), it shows another way to [start play as a service](https://github.com/opensas/play2-openshift-quickstart/blob/master/.openshift/action_hooks/start) and how to [stop it](https://github.com/opensas/play2-openshift-quickstart/blob/master/.openshift/action_hooks/stop).

basically you do something like this to start:

```
APP_COMMAND="${OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR}target/start $PLAY_PARAMS "\
"-Dhttp.port=${OPENSHIFT_INTERNAL_PORT} "\
"-Dhttp.address=${OPENSHIFT_INTERNAL_IP} "\
"-Dconfig.resource=openshift.conf"

echo $APP_COMMAND &>> $LOG_FILE
nohup bash -c "${APP_COMMAND} &>> ${LOG_FILE} 2>&1" &> /dev/null &
```

and to stop it

```
pid=`cat RUNNING_PID`
echo "Stopping play application" >> $LOG_FILE
kill -SIGTERM $pid
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, but it doesn't solve my problem. This works when I run it locally on a server, but I cannot trigger this remotely for some reason (e.g. with capistrano)

Comment: I made it working based on your suggestion (see https://gist.github.com/2769718) Key to the solution was not to use capistrano's default revision + symlink (current) directory structure, because the RUNNING_PID file will remain in an old sub directory of releases and the scripts are not able to stop the app anymore.

I'll mark this as an answer because I think it's the best way to deploy play applications

Answer (score 2):

There are few fresh topics about running application available at Google Groups:

- [Start an application as a background process](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/play-framework/BlV4c3q8hxE)
- [When deployed on Ubuntu 10.04 cant detach from console](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/play-framework/G5Tsu3CF4os)

It's good idea to follow or join them

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using runit. We are currently running a bunch of services in production and it works great.

It only involves creating a simple shell script named run, pointing runit to its containing directory and then start it. Services should not daemonize by themselves and runit controls pid files, etc.

There is a command ( `sv` ) to start, stop and query services. ( `sv start|stop|status|restart yourapp` ).

A cursory google search got me this http://rubygems.org/gems/capistrano-runit though I do not use capistrano at all so I can't vouch for it's usefulness.

http://smarden.org/runit/

The faq is the best place to start: http://smarden.org/runit/faq.html

In debian you just `apt-get install runit` and are good to go.
`update-service --add /your/service/dir/` will register the service with runit.

On deployment we stop services, change binaries and start services; it is really simple.

Comment: Sounds like a workable solution, but my question was really specific for play applications. I'll try if I can get it to work with runit.

Comment: It works with any kind of applications. If you are succesfull, please post back your experiences.